# Cross platform project structuring

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, projects-and-solutions

I am building a cross platform C# application.

All platforms share significant amount of code by using:

- Cross platform libraries (work with all platforms), for example a Portable Class Library project.
- Specific platform libraries (a separate DLL per platform).

Each platform may need some different bootstrapping code of its own, or some other customized version of certain parts.

I am looking for specific guidelines on how to set up a project (structuring) to accommodate for multiple platforms successfully.

Comment: what do you mean by platform? 32/64bit? mono/monotouch/microsoft? silverlight/compactframwork/winforms?

Comment: Platform is for example, PC, mobile (windows phone), android, etc.

Answer (score 0):

By far I only involved in one of such discussions,

http://sharpsnmplib.codeplex.com/discussions/390251

But the approach mel used, as demonstrated in https://github.com/moljac/MonoMobile.SharpSNMP does not convince me that it is the best way.

I am a subscriber to Monologue and so far I did not see any significant post from that source about this question. I think everyone is still researching/experimenting.